# Как избавиться от ошибки Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

Все работает, но в консоли у меня ошибка.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null

```js
methodName();

function methodName() {
  let alldivs = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
  let alldivsArr = Array.from(alldivs);

  for (var i = alldivsArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    alldivsArr[i].addEventListener('click', function asd() {
      console.log(i);
      var d = document.createElement('input');
      d.setAttribute("class", "myInput");
      d.setAttribute("value", this.innerText);
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(d, this);
      d.select();

      d.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        let g = document.createElement('div');
        g.setAttribute("class", "myBtn");
        g.innerHTML = d.value;

        d.parentNode.replaceChild(g, d);
        // removeIventLis();
        methodName();

      })
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myBtn">lolk</div>
<div class="myBtn">lolkasdasd</div>


<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в вызове `methodName`, внутри обработчика `blur`.

Так как внутри этого метода добавляются обработчики всем выбранным элементам на странице, а не только что добавленным, у некоторых элементов оказывается сразу несколько обработчиков клика. Поэтому при клике на них, на втором обработчике у `this` уже нет `parentNode` так как элемент уже был заменен на input.

Для решения достаточно вручную добавить обработчик вновь создаваемому элементу.

```js
methodName();

function methodName() {
  let alldivs = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
  let alldivsArr = Array.from(alldivs);

  for (var i = alldivsArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    alldivsArr[i].addEventListener('click', function myBtnClickHandler() {
      console.log(i);
      var d = document.createElement('input');
      d.setAttribute("class", "myInput");
      d.setAttribute("value", this.innerText);
      this.parentNode.replaceChild(d, this);
      d.select();
      d.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        let g = document.createElement('div');
        g.setAttribute("class", "myBtn");
        g.innerHTML = this.value;
        g.addEventListener('click', myBtnClickHandler);
        this.parentNode.replaceChild(g, this);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myBtn">lolk</div>
<div class="myBtn">lolkasdasd</div>


<button id="btn">Click</button>
```